# Firefox input type=date min not opening on minimum valid month

Tags: date, firefox, input, datepicker

I'm not sure if there's a way around this, but Firefox doesn't play nicely when you're using `input type="date"` with a `min=` attribute: It always open the datepicker on the *current* month, rather than the month where the minimum valid date begins. This is particularly annoying if the date is in the future.

For example:

`<input type="date" min="2021-08-04">`

(See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45oy50pL/) in Firefox.)

[image]

The user has to manually scroll through months until they finally get to the one that's available. Less than ideal!

Comment: The date-picker shows the calendar of the month you key in. It will display the calendar of August if you key in 08 in the month part,

Comment: @ildflue I really don't follow you

Comment: Are you fine with adding a default value? `<input type="date" min="2021-08-08" value="2021-08-08">` The downside is you have to add a default value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to *bypass* this behaviour is to set a value to the input as suggested in the comments. Instead of setting `value` attribute in the HTML, you can try to set it programmatically when the user clicks on the input and the datepicker is shown.

I think that `focus`/`focusin` are the best events to use to catch, since as far as I know there is no *`show`*/*`open`* events on [`input[type="date"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

On [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), in the Events sections are mentioned only `change` and `input`.

Here a live sample:

```js
var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
dateControl.addEventListener("focus", function(){
  // You can add validation on value
  if( this.min && !this.value ){
    this.value = this.min;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="date" min="2021-08-08">
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is the best solution if there's no way to tell FF natively

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp "Note: The min attribute will not work for dates and time in Internet Explorer 10+ or Firefox, since IE 10+ and Firefox does not support these input types." this is your best shot...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a really great solution as the browser can be tricked any time.

But this should work too.

HTML : `<input id="dateInput" type="date" min="2021-08-08">`

You can identify the browser of the client if it is Firefox and change the date automatically to become the minimum through this JS:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
document.getElementById("dateInput").value = document.getElementById("dateInput").min; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use value attribute to set the default value.

```
<input type="date" min="2021-08-04" value="2021-08-04">
```